# End to end encryption between c++ client and server via openssl & curl problems

Tags: php, c++, encryption, openssl

I've been working on implementing end-to-end encryption for my C++ client and server using OpenSSL. To accomplish this, I've created a PHP script that generates a public-private key pair. The script saves the client's key in a .pem file and echoes back the server's public key to the client. So far, this process works smoothly. I'm able to encrypt a string using the server's public key without any issues.

However, I encounter a problem when attempting to decrypt the encrypted message on the server side. I've developed a simple PHP script for decryption, but it returns OpenSSL errors, specifically: OpenSSL Error: error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error

I've tried to debug by checking if any data changes during transmission between the client and the server, but haven't found any discrepancies.

I'm at a loss and would greatly appreciate any assistance or insights into resolving this issue. Thank you.

code:

```c++
int main() {
    // create gui.
    menu::create_h_window("test window");
    menu::create_device();
    menu::create_imgui();

    // exchange keys.
    key_exchange exchanger;
    exchanger.exchange_keys();

    std::string test_message = "This is a test message";
    std::string encrypted_message = exchanger.encrypt_message(test_message, exchanger.server_public_key);

    curl_request request;
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    char* encoded_message = curl_easy_escape(curl, exchanger.base64_encode(encrypted_message).c_str(), 0);
    std::string post_fields = "message=" + std::string(encoded_message);
    curl_free(encoded_message);
    std::string server_response = request.post_request("https://example.org/test_encryption.php", post_fields);

    while (menu::b_is_running) {
        menu::begin_render();
        menu::render();
        menu::end_render();

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(5));
    }

    // destroy gui.
    menu::destroy_imgui();
    menu::destroy_device();
    menu::destroy_h_window();

    return 0;
}
```

```php
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    if (!isset($_POST['message'])) {
        echo "Error: Message not received";
        exit;
    }

    if (!file_exists('server_private_key.pem')) {
        echo "Error: Private key file not found";
        exit;
    }

    $private_key = file_get_contents('server_private_key.pem');

    if (!$private_key) {
        echo "Error: Invalid private key";
        exit;
    }
    $encrypted_message = base64_decode($_POST['message']);

    if (!openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted_message, $decrypted_message, $private_key, OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING)) {
        while ($msg = openssl_error_string()) {
            echo "OpenSSL Error: " . $msg . "\n";
        }
        exit;
    }
    echo $decrypted_message;
?>
```

```c++
std::string encrypt_message(const std::string& message, const std::string& other_public_key) {
    BIO* bio = BIO_new_mem_buf(other_public_key.data(), other_public_key.size());
    EVP_PKEY* evp_pkey = PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(bio, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (evp_pkey == nullptr) {
        unsigned long err = ERR_get_error();
        char* err_str = ERR_error_string(err, NULL);
        std::cout << "Error: " << err_str << std::endl;
    }

    RSA* other_rsa = EVP_PKEY_get1_RSA(evp_pkey);
    BIO_free(bio);
    int rsa_size = RSA_size(other_rsa);
    unsigned char* encrypted = new unsigned char[rsa_size];
    int encrypted_len = RSA_public_encrypt(message.size(), reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(message.data()), encrypted, other_rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
    std::string encrypted_str(reinterpret_cast<char*>(encrypted), encrypted_len);
    delete[] encrypted;
    RSA_free(other_rsa);
    EVP_PKEY_free(evp_pkey);
    return encrypted_str;
}
```

Comment: Removed the curl tag. I don't think curl is somehow mangling your HTTP request data.

Comment: It would realyl help if you provided a [mcve]. For one, it would answer the question whether the key generation is the problem or the encryption/decryption. I also notice some non idiomatic code there, so consider submitting it to codereview.stackexchange.com once you have it working.

Comment: You completely misunderstood the `RSA_size` function. Since that does not depend on the `message` at all, how can it possibly tell you how large the buffer should be? I highly suggest you use a more high-level library such as [libsodium's sealed boxes](https://doc.libsodium.org/public-key_cryptography/sealed_boxes) because OpenSSL is full of footguns like this.

Comment: RSA can only encrypt smallish strings. I'm not sure if that's the problem in your code or something else, so I do concur with the other comments about providing a [mre] and/or using a higher-level library so that you can avoid trying to become an expert on [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) using RSA.

Comment: I fixed the problem and I successfully got end to end encryption working. You can mark this post as solved if that's a thing here!